# Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '...'

Tags: typescript

[Type 'never[]' is not assignable to type '...'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PL0vt.png)

I am unable to initialize the property *items* on my class due to this random error. I figured extending the generic class type to `Array<string>` would ensure that the type is always a string array?

```
class MyClass<TItems extends Array<string>> {
    constructor() {
        this.items = [];
    }

    public items: TItems;
}
```

Gives me the error:

> Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'TItems'.
> 'string' is assignable to the constraint of type 'TItems', but 'TItems' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'string'.ts(2322)

Answer (score 2):

### Problem

You might be familiar of the fact that a subtype can be assigned to a supertype but vice-versa is not true. So, in the following code and the inline explanation-

```js
class A extends Array<string> {
  public myProp!: string
}

// it is ok to assign a subtype to its supertype
// because subtype has atleast all those props/methods
// that a supertype has
declare const a1: A
const array1: Array<string> = a1

// it is an error to assign supertype to one of its subtype
// (until they are structurally same)
// because the supertype (array2) may have some missing props/methods
// (myProp in this case) that its subtype has.
declare const array2: Array<string>
const a2: A = array2
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=17&pc=1#code/MYGwhgzhAECC0FMAeAXBA7AJjWAnXYAngDwQq4CW6A5gHzQDeAUNNAA4CuARiBcNAFtCABVwB7NgEIAXNDKUaTAL5MmAejXQKKLTDEBraCjHRIECtXSm53FITYIjJ7TAgcHuOw-WauCYGAcEI5uXF6OABaQpiggCJA6YCAgRhFiwezibBBqAggoadg+qWCJNh7h0FEQTJj+4LiOwGLoZKYAjLKwTM2tifhEnXADJPJUdNAAvB2qGlo6FDBgVgj4YrhOplAWVm4V9o7G0C2OYgBm8662B8UAFBzoKBQpBQiEpo1y5BzAKBwEyXeEDAeQAlMU-AEgocIiF3KtKrcwCMAEygwREKpgABuITEeUEi3MNEyEhyeQKYiKc1uQlEEi0VgKi2gAWC6IKpUuNjCByxEAAdLV6simi02siCIQUV0RqRyONaD1xYkZXAph8pSimEA)

In your code, `TItems` is a subtype of `Array<string>`, and type of `[]` is `never[]`.

If you had typecast-ed it with `[] as Array<string>`, the supertype (`Array<string>`) could not be assigned to subtype `TItems`. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVAkgFwKYFsZcAPPAOwBMYBBAJ1rHlQm1oEsyBzAPm+gG8AUNBHQADgFcARiDbBobPIQBc0LEogBuYaJ0jgAezItaE4NgO0AFAEoBe0SOwALNhAB0igjAC80ANoAutCQ0HQMTCYcPNqOAL6CcUA)

If you had typecast-ed it with `[] as TItems`, the typecasting is itself erroneous for the very same reason. [Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=7&pc=2#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVAkgFwKYFsZcAPPAOwBMYBBAJ1rHlQm1oEsyBzAPm+gG8AUNBHQADgFcARiDbBobPIQBc0LEogBuYaJ0jgAezItaE4NgO0AFAEoBe0SOwALNhAB0igjAC80ANoAutCQajje2o4AvoJRQA)

### Solution

The error could be get ridden of the error with typecasting as-

```js
class MyClass<TItems extends Array<string>> {
    public items: TItems;

    constructor() {
        this.items = [] as unknown as TItems;
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyCeBhcUA8AVAkgFwKYFsZcAPPAOwBMYBBAJ1rHlQm1oEsyBzAPm+gG8AUNBHQADgFcARiDbBobPIQBc0LEogBuQcNHAA9mRa0JwbPtoAKAJQDdo0dgAWbCADpFBGAF5oAbQBdaEhoCTIAazJ9AHcyYJh1L20HAF9BFKA)

But this may result in runtime errors because it's not a "safe" typecasting.

To avoid runtime errors, the correct way is to initialise the prop `items` with the constructor of the class `TItems` or function that returns `TItems` instead of `= []`. This will eliminate the type errors and also will ensure that there will be no runtime errors. Both ways are demonstrated-

```js
// if a passed TItems is supposed to class
// we pass that constructor of the class 
// constructor of `MyClass`
class MyClass<TItems extends Array<string>> {
    public items: TItems;

    constructor(ctor: new () => TItems) {
        this.items = new ctor();
    }
}

class MyArray extends Array<string> {
  private myProp!: string
}

const myClassVar = new MyClass(MyArray)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=16&pc=40#code/PTAEEsDNQQ1AHGBnJBTAJqAKgSQC6oC2SEJSArvPAPZqZ7WgDGANskgFAigDuqC7UHgAWMPM2oA7JHgBO5Jg1mhq0Ef1aCuYJlJnzF1ZatAADALIBPAMJsUpjppSgrt9gB5cBYqFQAPAkl0EgBBWVkYS3d9cEkAcwA+BNAAbw5QDIRyACMWcCYIbyQALmx8IiQAbg50zN1pOQUlAApDWVLJVB5QZoBKUABeZK8K-rTMiaFhcCQAOnAiwdBO7ra+6omAXw5txzsSKzCIy18A1CDQ8MjouVjE1Nr4WXAANzF+QksABVlqeABCUoxeI7Gr1GSgT5uFAANRgygGyy6Lhs+2ahyull6QA)

```js
// if a passed TItems is supposed to be just a type
// we pass a function that will create that object of `TItems`
class MyClass<TItems extends Array<string>> {
    public items: TItems;

    constructor(fn: () => TItems) {
        this.items = fn();
    }
}

declare function createObject(): Array<string> & { myProp: string }

const myClassVar = new MyClass(createObject)
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=1&ssc=1&pln=13&pc=45#code/PTAEEsDNQQ1AHGBnJBTAJqAKgSQC6oC2SEJSArvPAPZqZ7WgBGqoAVuUnrKHgJ7xUAKBCgA7q0QoekcgDsAxnnDU5vABYxuY8ABtdoBQCdUW1nk3dqTNqiWhq0AAa4CxJ0IW7kJALJ8AYW8UAB5XIhJUAA8COXQSAEEjIxg+EK4jcDkAcwA+XNAAbyFQUoRyJl1wBQg3JAAubHwIgG4hErKFVQzyJWojAApIOUaBgEpQAF4C8OIJ4rLFjXAkADpwOqnQYfG2xYBfIUOhdDtvE235JRU1Y1MCAHkbOzxxxqSUtIysvNAAMiKoEIfAACkZqPBGt8cqBjl05FwgYFgkgAGowIxbOSoMSgfxBHwDO5mJ62JRjIA)